# How to flatten the results of a Hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate

Say I executed a theoretical HQL query like `FROM Customer`.  And in `Customer` is a `getOrders()` getter returning a ManyToOne collection of `Order` objects.  This executes a SQL statement selecting from Customer with a left join to Order.

Through the object model, I can programmaticly iterate over Customers and then iterate over Orders.

However, I want to convert the hierarchical object model to a flat tabular result of the left join so that the results would look much like that of this SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer
LEFT JOIN Order on Customer.customerId = Order.customerId
```

Sample result:

```
Customer.customerId  ... Order.orderId  Order.customerId ...
1                        200            1
2                        201            2
2                        202            2
3                        NULL           NULL
```

Is there an easy way to do this with Hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you want at the "scalar" level which you control through using an explicitl select clause.

```
select c, o
from Customer c left join c.orders o
```

returns you List of (Customer, Order) tuples.  Or:

```
select c.id, c.name, o.id, ...
from Customer c left join c.orders o
```

which returns you a scalar projection of the atomic pieces.

In both cases you get back a List.  You can use "dynamic instantiation" in both cases (though really its more useful in the second case imho):

```
select new CustomerOrderSummary( c.id, c.name, o.id, ... )
from Customer c left join c.orders o
```

where CustomerOrderSummary is just a plain class with matching constructor.

Comment: Good detail on the 3 different ways of projecting the same data.

Comment: How do you use criteria query to achieve first example?

Answer (score 0):

Possible you can do this via expressing of result set. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/query_native.html

From the example:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="GetNightAndArea", entities={
    @EntityResult(name="org.hibernate.test.annotations.query.Night", fields = {
        @FieldResult(name="id", column="nid"),
        @FieldResult(name="duration", column="night_duration"),
        @FieldResult(name="date", column="night_date"),
        @FieldResult(name="area", column="area_id")
    }),
    @EntityResult(name="org.hibernate.test.annotations.query.Area", fields = {
        @FieldResult(name="id", column="aid"),
        @FieldResult(name="name", column="name")
    })
})
```

Comment: This strategy appears to be used to go the other way, from tabular data to entity hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try retrieving results in Object[] e.g. below:

```
    EntityManager entityManager = EntityManager.getEntityManager();
    Query query= entityManager.createQuery("select cust, ord from Customer cust left outer join cust.orders ord where cust.customerId = :customerId");
    tradeQuery.setParameter("customerId", aCustomerId);
    List<Object[]> resultList = (List<Object[]>)query.getResultList();
```

The retrieved resultsList will be list of Object array containing Customer and Order objects in flat.

```
    if(!resultList.isEmpty()){
        Iterator<Object[]> iter = resultList.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            Object[] resultObj = (Object[])iter.next();
            Customer customer= (Customer )resultObj[0];
            Order order = (Order)resultObj[1];
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!